# Log4j Multiple Threads

Tags: java, log4j

I am adding ConsoleAppender to rootlogger for log4j as

```
BasicConfigurator.configure(new ConsoleAppender(layout, "System.err"));
```

But somehow log messages in some loggers down the hierarchy are not reaching console. I have not seen any instance in the hierarchy setting the additivity flag as false.

Some loggers are running in different threads, do you I need to do any configuration? How can I debug this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Log4j is thread-safe. See [Is log4j thread-safe?](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#a1.7). You should not need any special configuration for multi-threading.

However, the messages can appear in a mixed-up order from different threads, so check that they aren't somewhere else in the logs.